# AngularJS unable to load view

Tags: angularjs

**Index.html**

```
<html ng-app="studentApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular.js Example</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src=".././app/component/studentApp.module.js"></script>
  <script src=".././app/component/studentApp.route.js"></script>
  <script src=".././app/component/list/list.ctrl.js"></script>
  <script src=".././app/component/list/list.html"></script>
  <script src=".././app/component/list/list.factory.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../app/assets/style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="header">
  <h1>Welcome to my AngularJS Web App</h1>
  <h2>Angular JS UI</h2>
</div>


<div ui-view> </div>

<div class="footer"style="bottom: 0px">
  <h2>This is my footer</h2>
  <h3>Copyright</h3>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**studentApp.route.js**

```
angular.module('studentApp').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('list');

  $stateProvider

    .state('list', {
        url: '/list',
        templateUrl: '.././component/list/list.html',
        controller: 'studentCtrl'
      })
});
```

**studentApp.module.js**

```
//(function (){
    "use strict";
    angular.module('studentApp', [
        'ui.router'
        ])
//}());
```

**list.ctrl.js**

```
angular.module('studentApp').controller('studentCtrl', function($scope,$state ,$http) {

    alert("here");

});
```

[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2m2AJ.png)

I'm trying to load **list.html** in **index.html** but unsuccessful every time.

I m getting errors:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

**Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `index.html`, you loaded `angular-route.min.js` that is the default route manager for AngularJS.

Your code wants to use instead `angular-ui-router.min.js`, that is a popular [routing library](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

Try to replace

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Its giving me error in **Google Chrome** showing  _italic_Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource. _italic_

However working on Firefox with a error **SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'**

Comment: following [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10752078/1218213), you are loading form `file://`?  What IDE are you using? (Are you a student, isn't it?)

Comment: Thanks Its working now on localhost,
I m using WebStrom and yes I m a student

Comment: I recognized WebStorm and I knew that it has a ready-to-use local server, but, well, you discovered before :) very good!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your app setup.

Each sub-module (controllers, services etc) needs to have it's own module name. So your sub-modules should look like this:

**list.ctrl.js**

```
angular.module('studentApp.controller', [])
.controller('studentCtrl', function($scope,$state ,$http) {

    alert("here");

});
```

**studentApp.route.js**

```
angular.module('studentApp.route', [])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('list');

  $stateProvider

.state('list', {
    url: '/list',
    templateUrl: '.././component/list/list.html',
    controller: 'studentCtrl'
  })
});
```

And then you need to inject your sub-modules into your main module:

**studentApp.module.js**

```
angular.module('studentApp', ['studentApp.route', 'studentApp.controller', 'ui.router'])
```

And then as the other answers mention, you need to change your library, since you are using `ui-router` instead of Angular's default router.

Answer (score 0):

https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular-route.min.js is route provider which is default router in angular js.

Since you want to stateprovider, have a look into this github which helps to use the stateprovider

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 0):

Along with the other two answers,

Please remove `<script src=".././app/component/list/list.html"></script>`

If you need to include list.html in Index.html, you do it like

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="../../app/component/list/list/html">
content
<script/>
```

Please ensure that this path is correct.
`templateUrl: '.././component/list/list.html',` shouldn't there be two `..`'s instead of 1?